# What type is this a typedef of?

Tags: c++, c

I encountered this declaration in some code I was looking at which I don't understand.

```cpp
typedef struct foo_* foo;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   foo a = nullptr;    // Ok. foo is a synonym for 'foo_*'
   foo_* b = a;  // Ok! somehow foo_* is a valid type, but where is it defined?

   return 0;
}
```

The type `foo_` is not previously defined or declared (this is a complete compiling sample). It was my understanding that a `typedef` provides a synonym for types that already exist, and types cannot be used until declared or defined. Since `foo_` is not previously declared or defined what is this a `typedef` of and how is that legal?

UPDATE:

Some are saying that this is ok because the struct foo_* in the typedef is assumed to be an inline forward declaration and that actually attempting to use foo_ will fail. But I've just tested this on VS2012 and referencing this type compiles fine for me.

Comment: Don't put the answer in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you get off my back please?

Comment: I don't want to add a new answer to my own question and accept that as the answer since the response by πάντα ῥεῖ did all the work yet does not provide the fuller background to the issue that I am able to add.

Comment: Answers go in the answer section, not in the question. I'm not "on your back", I am reminding you how this website works (again). Posting an answer to your own question is absolutely fine and _encouraged_. You don't have to accept it if you don't want to. However, putting an answer in the question is downright wrong and will always be edited out.

Comment: I can't even accept my own answer so that's useful isn't it.

Comment: Yes, you can. But you just said yourself that you don't want to anyway. What's the problem? Do you think an answer that's not accepted is useless? Wrong! Just post your findings as an answer. And quit adding a second language back into the tags. The code you are talking about is either C code, or C++ code. As posted, it is C++ code.

Comment: If there is a problem, it's that in posting this simple programming question I've had more work and feedback on the issue of how well I'm conforming to the SO regulations that I have on the issue in question, which seems unnecessary, is irritating, and seems to be becoming the norm on this site these days. On topic, the use of keyword 'struct' in the typedef appears to be a C idiom and the use of this technique appears to be intended to maintain C compatibility, (even though my sample is indeed C++).

Comment: If you were to follow site guidelines instead of violating them constantly then the curators wouldn't have to keep "getting on your back" about it. Yes this is mostly a holdover from C and its continued usage almost certainly a compatibility thing. It wouldn't pass code review in my C++ team, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by πάντα ῥεῖ is correct, but I've been forced by the SO police to add my own answer in order to provide a fuller context instead of just updating the question, so apologies to πάντα ῥεῖ for accepting this and not his answer.

A typedef of the form in the question is a slightly more obtuse form of the code below, and while the value of a pointer to a forward declared type can be read and set, the memory address the pointer points to cannot accessed without the full type definition.

```cpp
struct A;  // Forward declaration, undefined.

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   A* a;   // Ok. Don't need type definition to create a pointer.
   a = 0;  // Ok. Can set pointer value without definition.

   if(*a)  // Error. "incomplete type is not allowed".
   {}      // Without a definition Any attempt to access the pointer is an error.

   int* b;
   a = b;  // Error. "int* cannot be assigned to entity of type A*".
           // Even without having seen a definition for A the 
           // compiler will still enforce type safety.  

   return 0;
}
```

In the code where I'm seeing it (in the OpenCL C header definitions of cl_platform_id et al.) this technique seems to be being used in order to specify a type that is used to store ID values in a variable whose storage class matches a pointer type in the current environment, but which cannot be accidentally accessed as a pointer.

This calls to mind the technique used in the Windows headers where a void* is typedeffed as type HANDLE, and then macros are used to define pointers to concrete structure types as different types of HANDLES. The technique used in the OpenCL headers seems to achieve stronger type safety while not requiring any struct types to be actually defined.

Whether the hit in readability that's taken by using a technique as obtuse as using forward declared but undefined types in order to maximise type safety is a worthwhile trade off is a matter of opinion, and if C compatibility were not required (as it is in OpenCL) then I expect there is probably a more elegant way to achieve the same result in C++, although I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 5):

> Since `foo_` is not previously declared or defined what is this a `typedef` of and how is that legal?

It will complain as soon you want to do any useful with it. Forward declared pointers are OK, but dereferencing needs the complete type.

```
typedef struct foo_* foo;

int main()
{
    foo bar;
    foo_ baz = *bar;
}
```

fails with a compile error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:10: error: variable 'foo_ baz' has initializer but incomplete type
     foo_ baz = *bar;
          ^
```

Comment: I think your right, and I think that also explains why it's been used in the specific case I'm seeing, but before I update my question and mark this as the answer are you able to provide a citation for completeness please, standard link or something?

Answer (score 2):

In C++:
While it might be a bit confusing, you can combine a forward declaration and usage of a type.

```
struct foo_;
typedef foo_* foo;
```

Combined:

```
typedef struct foo_* foo;
```

In C, you cannot split this typedef because usage of struct must contain the keyword struct. You also don't need to forward declare structs in C, so it is the usual syntax.